Help Needed: Looking for Sample Phase Change Material (PCM) Calculations
I am working on implementing a Phase Change Material (PCM) system for a cold storage facility. While I'm familiar with traditional refrigeration systems, I'm relatively new to PCM technology and would appreciate some guidance on the calculations involved.
Specifically, I'm looking for assistance in determining the following parameters for an effective PCM system:
Mass of PCM Required
PCM Cooling Capacity
PCM Discharge Time & Cycles
Re-Freeze Time
Electricity Consumption for Re-freezing

Provided PCM Specifications:
Ambient Temperature (Ta): 32°C
Chilled Storage Temperature (Tc): ≈ 2°C
Latent Heat of Fusion (Solid/Liquid): 213 kJ/kg & 271 kJ/kg
Specific Heat (Solid/Liquid): 3.86 kJ/kg.K & 5.96 kJ/kg.K
Melting Temperature (Tm): 6°C
Freezing Temperature (Ts): 5°C
Density (Solid/Liquid): 727 kg/m³ & 763 kg/m³
Thermal Conductivity (Solid/Liquid): 0.13 W/mK & 0.12 W/mK
Wall U-value: 0.425 W/m²K

Missing Information (Assumptions Welcome):
Wall Areas and Room Volume
Mass & Cooling Load of Stored Goods
Heat Gain Rate of the Storage Unit

Initial Calculations and Concerns:
Based on preliminary calculations, the daily electricity consumption for the PCM system appears to be around 90% of a traditional refrigeration system. This seems surprisingly high. Can you offer insights into this discrepancy or potential errors in my calculations?
Additional Infrastructure:
Beyond the PCM containers/tabs, what other infrastructure components are essential for a smooth-functioning PCM cold storage system?
Thank you in advance for your valuable expertise and guidance.
Sincerely,
Milan

The question is quite broad, you may need to narrow it down to increase potential of getting answers (or you can split it into more questions). When you mention preliminary calculation and ask for insights into potential errors, its beneficial if you include these calculations. Why is latent heat of fusion different for solid and liquid?
